# Where is the query plan from an SSRS report rendering

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-execution-plan

Hi I have a simple question. But it lead to another question. I want to delete the query plan for a stor proc i ran.  So I ran the proc using

```
exec dbo.uspNameOfProc
```

and then checked the plan chace using the query

```
SELECT [text], cp.size_in_bytes, plan_handle
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp CROSS APPLY 
     sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)
where [text] like '%uspNameOfProc%'
```

what else am i missing?

Comment: Try searching on some of the text within the proc, I don't think the specific call to the proc would be included in the query plan cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RUN `exec dbo.uspNameOfProc` Then Run [sp_who3](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/a-better-sp_who2-using-dmvs-sp_who3) Find out which spid it is running under.

```
Then run USE master;
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
WHERE session_id = YourSPID;
GO
```

This will get you the Plan handle. To see the execution plan run.

```
USE master;
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_plan (YourPlanHandleID);
GO
```

Then if you wish to clear the plan from cache use this.

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (YourPlanHandleID);
GO
```

Hope that helps. 
UPDATE*****
Make sure perform these operations on separate query windows so as to not alter the execution plan.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly easier way to get the plan handle (since you're using a stored procedure) would be from sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats. Something like (from your database):

```
select plan_handle
from sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats
where database_id = db_id()
   and object_id = object_id('dbo.uspNameOfProc');
```

Comment: that returns the query of the create proc though

Comment: The problem with searching this way is that there can be multiple plans per stored procedure which is why I'm having him run off of spid.

Comment: @Zane: I say that's a feature. At that point, you can choose which one (or ones) you want to delete.

Comment: @Mike_L: Every query plan that I've ever looked at for a stored proc is a create procedure statement, so your result isn't surprising.

Comment: yah im learnin stuff, after i looked at it again i saw there were constant values next to the variables

Comment: @BenThul the issue with that logic is how are you sure which plan is the one running from Reporting Services?

Comment: @Zane: If that's important, I'd use extended events over some "hurry up and run sp_who in another window" method. But it wasn't clear to me that it *was* important.